# Cribbage. Run of 5 or more

Tags: cribbage

I get that 4,6,5,7 is valid and scores 4 points.

If it was a run that goes past the four cards played, e.g. 4,6,5,7 then a 3 is played and then a 2.

Do the 3 and 2 continue the run and score 5 points and then 6 points?

Comment: Hi Papa Dingo, if you are satisfied that the answer given below satisfies your question, please take a minute to acknowledge the poster by giving them a green check mark in the accepted answer spot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Each card that makes a run during play scores the run.

From https://www.mastersofgames.com/rules/cribbage-rules.htm

> Similarly, if anyone lays a card such that with the three or more preceding cards, a run can be constructed, the number of cards which would make up that run are scored. e.g. suppose cards were laid in the following order: 8,6,4,5,7. The fourth card would score 3 points, the fifth card would score five points.

See for more: http://cribbagecorner.com/node/536